# Difference between「のびる／のばす」and「のべる」

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

With the use of a dictionary, along with reading some web pages, I understood the  meaning as well as the proper usage of 「延びる／延ばす」and 「伸びる／伸ばす」. But I noticed an overlapping in meaning regarding「延べる」and「伸べる」. Do the former two groups of verbs have differences in meaning and usage with「延べる」and「伸べる」.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Difference のびる／のばす and のべる

のべる has meaning as `make flat something thick or fold`.

> 1. 空間的に長くする。また、広くする。
>
>    - ㋐たたんであるものなどをひろげる。敷く。「布団を―・べる」
>    - ㋑（「手をのべる」の形で）対象に向かって届かせるように手をのばす。積極的にさし出す。さしのべる。「手を―・べて助けおこす」「救いの手を―・べる」
>    - ㋒かたまり状の物を、打って均質に薄く広げる。「飴(あめ)を―・べる」「金(きん)を―・べる」
>
> [伸べる／延べる(ノベル)とは - コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BC%B8%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B-597279)

On the other hand, のびる has wider meanings. But,  のびる's meaning of `make flat` is used for thinner thing.

> 1. ものの長さ・高さ・広がりが増す。
>
>    - ㋔（伸びる）全体にうすく、均質にひろがる。「よく―・びる塗料」
>
> [伸びる／延びる(ノビル)とは - コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BC%B8%E3%81%B3%E3%82%8B-597202)

For better comprehension, I'll explain about other differences.

## Difference of 延 and 伸, in meaning of extension

### 延

> 時間が予定より長びく。「延引・延滞／順延・遅延」
>
> [伸べる／延べる(ノベル)とは - コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BC%B8%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B-597279)

延 has meaning as `extending schedule`.

### 伸

> まっすぐのびる。長くのばす。「伸縮・伸張・伸展／引伸・急伸・屈伸」
>   [伸(シン)とは - コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BC%B8-536532)

伸 has meaning as `extend straightly`.

I think 伸 is used with a thing which has form, but I couldn't find source about it.

## Difference of 伸べる and 延べる

Same.

See again [伸べる／延べる(ノベル)とは - コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BC%B8%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B-597279). These are used as a same word.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that のべる and のばす are 他動詞 / transitive verbs, whereas のびる is a 自動詞 or intransitive verb.